# Wiley 15.10: Some windows are not visible

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, display-manager

Right after installing Wiley 15.10 from iso image, I discovered that some windows are not showing up:

- The terminal, when you press CTRL+ALT+T
- The Chrome Browser which has been the 1st I've installed right after

Both are open, but not showing up. They don't even show up when I want to switch to the window by using ALT-TAB.

That must be a bug, I did not even change any settings.

Comment: By any chance a second monitor connected, but switched off? If not, what does System Settings > Monitors show?

Comment: that is it! you can list the screens in terminal using `xrandr`, too, but there is only one connected.

Answer (score 0):

My monitor had an extra HDMI cable connected, that's why the system has detected a 2nd screen which did not exist.
Removing it has solved the problem. Thanks to Jacob Vlijm!